# Why are visual studio pdb files so much larger than elf debug symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a project that compiles with Visual Studio 2010. The build process for this project is outside of my control, and I can only modify source code, so there may be some setting that I'm not aware of that is causing this behavior.

However, I notice that the project that I'm working on, which has something on the order of a megabyte or two worth of source code, is being created with pdb several pdb files and some of them are larger than 100 MB.

I have a build-from source Linux system on another computer (Gentoo Linux) that has all of the debug symbols from all installed applications, automatically saved in /usr/lib/debug, and that entire directory is only 600MB. So, on Linux, 2GB of compressed source code turn out 600MB of debug information, but on Windows, 1-2MB turns out 100's of MB's of debug information?

Where does this huge difference in size come from?

Comment: See: http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Visual Studio will instruct to generate the PDB files with as much information as possible, you can configure it to generate smaller files through the settings of the project (the exact steps depend on the type of project, for C# you can find it under:

> [ProjectProperties] -> <kbd>build</kbd> -> <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> -> Output / Debug Info.

Setting it to pdb-only will generate much smaller files, but will provide less help when debugging locally.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question of why Visual Studio generates so much more information compared to a significantly larger amount of source code on linux, but I marked your answer as accepted since you're the only one who replied.